# function is not defined when im trying to call a function inside my onsubmit function

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

i have this form say

```
<form onSubmit={this.formSubmit} id="userForm" name="myForm" noValidate>
```

im trying to call another function inside my formsubmit() function but it says the function is not defined . what could the reason be

```
   formSubmit=(e)=>{
    e.preventDefault();
    validateForm();
  }
  validateForm=()=>{
    console.log("test")
  }
```

Comment: Asalamu, Alykum ! Would like to  see your full code. Full Component Code. 
Either update your question or use codesandbox and share the link with me. I would fix it InshaAllah

Comment: valaykkum asalam brother .. well its fixed now :) .. i just had to call the function with this in front

Comment: yup, I saw. Glad it is solved :) One advise though.  You should avoid class based components and rather use Hooks. 

This could be helpful :) 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iZhV0bILFb0

It's been long time that I have not used Class Based Components. They are kind of deprecated now

Comment: yeah... bad thing is ive coded all the way using class components only . gonna learn hooks from tommorow . thanks .. ill check it out :)

Comment: Once you learn Hooks, You can convert all the class based components into Functional Components quite easily. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call `this.validateForm()`. `validateForm` is bound to the component instance.

Answer (score 0):

**formSubmit** and **validateForm** are methods of your (component) class, not an independent function. In order to call the inside of the class, you need to call it through the `this` keyword as it is bound to the class.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `this` key word in the Component it seems.
`this` key word has varying scope depending on where you are using it.